# Trying to automate a two step clicker via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to automate a clicker via JavaScript on Poshmark that clicks the "Share" button, then will follow up with a Modal click that directs where it will be shared to. I have the first step working just fine, which is set up as follows:

Editing the HTML to add an ID to this destination via Inspect:

```
//<div data-et-prop-unit_position="0" data-et-prop-listing_id="61f18166e107bb31e89df428" data-et-prop-lister_id="5bfc8b3f1bc870975273b78f" data-et-prop-location="listing_details" data-et-on-name="listing_details" data-et-name="share" data-et-element-type="button" ***id="shareButton"*** class="d--fl ai--c social-action-bar__action social-action-bar__share btn btn--tertiary btn--icon btn--small"><i class="icon share-gray-large btn__icon"></i><span>Share</span></div>
```

Then I run this from the console:

```
var shareButton = document.getElementById("shareButton");
setInterval(function(){
    shareButton.click()
},600)
```

This part works just fine, however this only opens the modal of the share location, which is:

```
<a data-et-name="share_poshmark" ***id= "shareDestination"*** class="internal-share__link"><div class="share-wrapper-container"><div class="share-wrapper__icon-container"><i class="icon pm-logo-white"></i></div><span class="share-wrapper__share-title caption">To My Followers</span></div></a>
```

I've added another ID before the class in this one. However, when I run this block of code it always gives me an error.

```
var shareDestination = document.getElementById("shareDestination");
setInterval(function(){
    shareDestination.click()
},700)
```

However, if I run this separately, it clicks on the share destination -once- then never again and doesn't loop the way the initial block of code does.

If I use them both, it just gives me errors.

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here? I am new to this, and appreciate it in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "errors?" Please be specific.

Comment: This is the specific error I am getting: VM216:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click')
    at <anonymous>:3:14

Comment: The result of `getElementById()` is null when there is no such an element. Could it be the extra space between the `id` and the `=` breaking it?

Comment: What happens when you `console.log()` the contents of `shareButton` and `shareDestination`?

Comment: When I console log shareDestination it says undefined and null. It does not appear to save the HTML I add to this section, but it does save the HTML I add to the first step. :/